# Best way to retrieve document with nested JSON and limit

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Suppose we have a structure:

```
{
  "nested_items": [
    {
      "nested_sample0": "1",
      "nested_sample1": "test",
      "nested_sample2": "test",
      "nested_sample3": {
        "type": "type"
      },
      "nested_sample": null
    },
    {
      "nested_sample0": "1",
      "nested_sample1": "test",
      "nested_sample2": "test",
      "nested_sample3": {
        "type": "type"
      },
      "nested_sample1": null
    },
    ...
  ],
  "sample1": 1233,
  "id": "ed68ca34-6b59-4687-a557-bdefc9ec2f4b",
  "sample2": "",
  "sample3": "test",
  "sample4": "test",
  "_ts": 1656503348
}
```

I want to retrieve documents by id by with limit of "nested_items" field .As I know limit and offset not supported in sub queries. Any way to do this except of divide into two queries? Maybe some udf or else?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by limit of "nested_items"? Possibly add some sample output you expect.

Comment: `nested_items` is an array - there is no limit defined there, just an array of other elements. What, exactly, are you trying to do? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: For example if this nested_items array have 1000 length. When I retrieve each document from container with query 'select * from c where id.='@id'' it return all objects from this array but I need only 100. So can I apply limit or offset operator for this array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `ARRAY_SLICE` assuming the array is ordered.

Example data:

```json
{
    "name": "John",
    "details": [
        {
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Example queries

```sql
-- First 2 items from nested array
SELECT c.name, ARRAY_SLICE(c.details, 0, 2) as details
FROM c
```

```sql
-- Last 2 items from nested array
SELECT c.name, ARRAY_SLICE(c.details, ARRAY_LENGTH(c.details) - 2, 2) as details
FROM c
```